# The coordinate system used for linearGradients in a nested svg element

Tags: svg

For `<linearGradient>`, the attribute gradientUnits defines the coordinate system used for the attributes x1, y1, x2, and y2. In the next example I'm using a linearGradient inside a nested SVG element. The value for `gradientUnits = "userSpaceOnUse"` is indicating that the attributes represent values in the coordinate system that results from taking the current user coordinate system in place at the time when the gradient element is referenced.

The gradient element is used inside a nested svg element with a different viewBox. Please observe that x2="100%"

```css
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 350 150"> 
<defs>
  <linearGradient id="usou"
x1="10" x2="100%" y1="10" y2="10" gradientUnits = "userSpaceOnUse">
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="hsl(120,100%,30%)"></stop>
   <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="hsl(320,100%,50%)"></stop>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
  <svg width="150" height="60" viewBox="0 0 250 100">
 <rect x="10" y="10" fill="url(#usou)" width="250" height="100"></rect>
</svg>
</svg>
```

The result is different in Chrome and Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

[image: Chrome]

Apparently Chrome is using the reference coordinate system of the parent svg while in Firefox using the reference coordinate system of the nested svg element.

Is Chrome or Firefox failing?

Comment: userSpaceOnUse is *the coordinate system that results from taking the current user coordinate system in place at the time when the gradient element is referenced (i.e., the user coordinate system for the element referencing the gradient element via a fill or stroke property)* So given that, I think Firefox is right.